# How to force C compiler to define function with argument long when declared with void*

Tags: c, function, gcc, compilation, void

While analyzing some library code supplied by another company we have come across strange construct (probably an error). In the header file a function was declared as:

```
int funct(type1 var1, type2 var2, void* usr_arg);
```

(sorry for general naming. NDA) But in the source file function of the same name was defined as:

```
int funct(type1 var1, type2 var2, long usr_arg)
{
    // code goes here;
}
```

And the most curious thing was, that while compiling with the makefile supplied, everything works fine. When we tried to configure eclipse project however, it refused compilation and pointed us at exactly two function headers stated above.

Compiler used in our case is gcc under ubuntu, however the library is supposed to work under windows as well. How can we make gcc accept this monstrosity?

Comment: Does this occur at many code locations, or is it only one function?

Comment: Maybe better to modify the header, as I assume there's only one file for its prototype?

Comment: how is the long usr_arg used in the function funct()?  Also out of curiosity, how old is this source code?  I have seen using a long to hold a pointer in older code that assumed that a pointer and a long were the same size in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very strange, the Makefile probably passes some flag to gcc to ignore that, or just issue a warning, while the eclipse project doesn't, or it could be that the eclipse project compiler flags are more strict. Anyway, I suggest you change the function declaration to match its definition (or the other way around depending on what the function actually expects) and the error will go away.

Comment: Then it is ok. But i see this typo much too often, that's why I provided this link... :-)

Comment: Looking at both makefile's and eclipses outputs suggests that only two differences between gcc invocations are: arguments' order and automatic dependency resolution by eclipse (-M flags). Unless we missed something. They were quite long. We modified definition to match declaration (as the code storet usr_arg in a field of pointer type)

Answer (score 1):

If the definition, e.g.

```
 int funct(type1 var1, type2 var2, long usr_arg)
 {
  // etc
 }
```

does not appear in a file which is including the header declaring

```
 int funct(type1 var1, type2 var2, void* usr_arg);
```

the GCC compiler usually cannot find any error.

I would suggest to use the [link time optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) ability of a recent GCC (i.e. GCC 4.6 or 4.7), that is to pass both at compilation and at link time the `-flto` flag (with some optimization flags).

<sup>I don't recommend using `-flto` with `gcc-4.5`; you really want at least GCC 4.6</sup>

A possible way to achieve that might be to run `make CC='gcc -Wall -flto -O2'`; this probably would have found that error.

<sup>Notice that `-flto` slows down the build time, because some optimizations are done both when compiling each source file and when linking every augmented object files into the executable or the library</sup>

If your code base is important enough, you could consider developping a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension to GCC for such purposes (MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC).

Comment: Out of historical curiosity: What was the problem with `-flto` in 4.5? (If you can give a short exposé)

Comment: AFAIR, LTO was quite buggy in 4.5 and crashed the compiler on some tests I made at that time. Current 4.7 GCC has an LTO working on most programs (I've even heard that with care, caution, and a big machine it is able to compile very big programs like firefox).

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on a few small things with 4.5, and it worked, so I wondered. It didn't do much for these, though, hardly any difference to `-O3`, if there was a speedup at all.

Comment: The source file in question does indeed include the header. (That's why eclipse throws an arror). We already solved this by modyfing definition to match declaration. Hope it won't break any future updates :) We'll probably try lto tomorrow. Compilation time is not an issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to fix the source (assumption: it is only a limited number of locations where this occurs). Assumed that the function is indeed called with a pointer (as in the declaration), you could change the definition like

```
int funct(int var1, int var2, void* usr_arg1) {
    long usr_arg = (long) usr_arg1;
    // code goes here;
}
```

Comment: As for now it has been reported twice. We are only attepting to build what we are using. We don't actually need to compile it with eclipse. Makefile works fine. It's only useful to have well configured eclipse for browsing the code (documentation is pretty poor).